# How to link containers in a "icc=false" bridge?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, network

I'd like to connect several services with a reverse proxy. But the services can't communicate with each others.

I'm using a compose file for each service.

I'm trying to use the same external bridge (icc=false).

After that, I don't understand how to allow the different communication with the reverse proxy. I've tried links and external_links but it doesn't work. Then, I have read that link will be deprecated...

Sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.
Thanks, have a good day.

```
#Example of Test1 compose file:
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: nicolaka/netshoot:latest
    tty: true
    restart: always
    networks:
      app-net:
    external_links:
      - test2-app-1
     
networks:
  app-net:
    external:
      name: bridge_icc_false #created with com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=false
```

Comment: I thought link allowed containers to talk w/each other even when icc was set to false. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I thought too. But link option is depracated. This is why I posted this question. I currently do BMitch's answer (see comments below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icc=false` means that inter-container communications are not allowed. If you want to allow inter-container communications, you need to run your containers on a network without this setting.

Comment: So, should I create one bridge per service ? And the reverse proxy is connected to all bridges ?

Comment: @Guix555 that's a common design with reverse proxies. The other is to have services that don't talk to each other and you trust on the same network.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch. This will quickly add several bridges. Is there a maximum ?

Comment: @Guix555 I think most people run out of private subnet ranges before hitting any other limits. I'm not sure there's a hard limit in docker.

Comment: Docker's default network pools allows for 31 custom bridge networks. The first 15 will be allocated from 172.168.17.0/12 as /16's - allowing ~65535 hosts each. the next 16 are allocated from the 192.168.0.0/16 block as /20's - allowing ~4095 hosts each. If/when swarmmode is activated, overlay networks are then allocated from 10.0.0.0/8 as /24s, allowing for just over 16 million networks, each with ~255 hosts.

Comment: How do I prevent some containers from talking to each other while allowing others? I thought we could do this w/link.

Comment: Link adds an entry to /etc/hosts, it predates using DNS, and is considered a legacy feature. To ask a new question, please use the "ask question" button.